# Why does this MySQLquery return zero results when the word "of" is included?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This query is returning zero results when it includes `+of` in the search terms:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
        FROM pin
        WHERE MATCH (
        title, 
        front, 
        back, 
        price, 
        sku, 
        datereleased, 
        edition, 
        wherefrom, 
        class, 
        categories, 
        details, 
        groups, 
        associated, 
        artist) 
        AGAINST ('+Pirates +of +the +Caribbean' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        ORDER BY pin.id DESC
```

Yet when I take it out, I get 1000+ rows:

```
'+Pirates +the +Caribbean'
```

Also, when I search with a phrase instead, I get 1000+ rows:

```
"Pirates of the Caribbean"
```

Why is the `+of` showing zero results? Are two character search words causing a problem in some way I am unaware of? I've noticed the same issues with the word `+to` as well.

Comment: This is likely a side effect of fulltext search. Terms that are present in more than 50% of records (IIRC) are dropped from the search and insisting they must show up turns up 0 results. Let me see whether I can find the manual link (Edit: ahhh it's minimum length, of course, you're right)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the word "of" to be included in fulltext searches there are two things you must do

## Set minimum word length

You will have to set the [**ft_min_word_len**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) to 1, by adding this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len = 1
```

## Include more common words

I wrote a [**post in the DBA StackExchange on Jan 26, 2012 about defining stopwords**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730).

By default, [there are 543 built-in words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) considered common.

## Suggestion

To create a stopword list, just make a text file and define it in `my.cnf`

To define the three Enlglish articles as stopwords, go to the OS and run this:

```
echo "a"    > /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "an"  >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "the" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
```

If you want all words, including `a`, `an`, and `the`, do this:

```
echo -n > /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
```

Next, add these lines to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=1
ft_stopword_file=/var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
```

Next, run `service mysql restart`

Finally, reindex the `pin` table like this:

```
REPAIR TABLE pin QUICK;
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my issue. Looks like `FULLTEXT` index searches have a `ft_min_word_len` value defaulted at 4 character words. I'll need to change it and rebuild my indexes if I want to search on smaller works.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Also (thanks Dan Bracuk):

> words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered
>   common and do not match.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know so I looked it up.  Found [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).  It includes this phrase:

In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match.